# Callback Listener is always null

Tags: android, kotlin

I can't figure it out why listener in class PageFragment > getChapterLink function is always null. I already set the listener in pageFragment. It took me so long debugging this code but I can't fix it anymore. Please help me. Thanks.

```
class ReaderFragment : Fragment() {
   private fun setPageRedirection() {
   val pageFragment = PageFragment()
   pageFragment.setChapterHrefCallbackListener(object: ChapterHrefCallback {
        override fun getChapterLink(href: String) {
           vPagerReaderPage.currentItem = pageAdapter!!.checkSpinePosition(href)
       }
   })
}

class PageFragment : Fragment(), ChapterHrefCallback {
   private var listener: ChapterHrefCallback? = null
      override fun getChapterLink(href: String) {
          Timber.d("HREF -----> $href")
          if (listener != null) {
              listener?.getChapterLink(href)
              Timber.d("HREF -----> " + listener?.getChapterLink(href))
   }
}

fun setChapterHrefListener(listener: ChapterHrefCallback?) {
   this.listener = listener
}

interface ChapterHrefCallback {
    fun getChapterLink(href: String)
}
```

Comment: Because `private var listener: ChapterHrefCallback? = null` and `setChapterHrefListener` does not reference to the listener inside `PageFragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the interface incorrectly, `PageFragment` doesn't need to implement the `ChapterHrefCallback`, you just need to call the method in it:

```
class PageFragment : Fragment() { // notice we remove the ChapterHrefCallback
   private var listener: ChapterHrefCallback? = null

   fun someFunctionHere() {
      //codes here...
      listener.getChapterLink("pass the link here")
      //codes again here...
   }
}
```

Then this will be handled by the `ReaderFragment`.

Comment: You can mark it as the correct answer so others can make it as a reference also. Thanks!